# How can I have an Apache server at a single IP which serves different content to requests for different domain names?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, virtualhost

I've seen this in the wild before: an Apache server that serves different sites to requests for different domain names, like so:

```
123.123.123.123
    ^ domainA.com
    ^ domainB.com
    ^ domainC.com
```

Each one of these domains should have a separate VirtualHost, as well as a global VirtualHost for all other requests (namely those coming directly to the IP address). How can I make this possible on my server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# this is into httpd.conf
NameVirtualHost *

# domain1.com
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName www.domain1.com
DocumentRoot /www/domain1
</VirtualHost>

# domain2.com
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName www.domain2.com
DocumentRoot /www/domain2
</VirtualHost>
```